# Deleting child collection from parent

Tags: php, doctrine, doctrine-orm

I'm going crazy.

This is the parent:

```
class Parent {
    /**
     * @Id
     * @GeneratedValue
     * @Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Core\Parent\Child", mappedBy="parent", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    protected $children;


    public function __construct() {
        $this->children = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }


    public function getChildren() {
        return $this->children->toArray();
    }

    public function removeAllChildren() {
        $this->children->clear();
    }

    public function addChild($child) {
        $this->children->add($child);
    }
}
```

This is the child:

```
class Child {
    /**
     * @Id
     * @GeneratedValue
     * @Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Core\Parent", inversedBy="children")
     * @JoinColumn(name="parent_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $parent;
}
```

What is not working for me is deleting all EXISTING children for this parent. From my controller, I do:

```
$parent = $em->getRepository('Core\Parent')->find(1);
$parent->removeAllChildren();
```

At this point, I can call `getChildren()` and it is empty. Before my script quits, I also do an: `$em->flush();`

However, I check the database tables and the data is still there! I don't get it, and it's driving me insane. How do I delete all the existing children for this parent?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use the [Orphan Removal](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.1/en/reference/working-with-associations.html#orphan-removal) option, eg

```
/**
 * @OneToMany(
 *   targetEntity="Core\Parent\Child",
 *   mappedBy="parent",
 *   orphanRemoval=true,
 *   cascade={"persist", "remove"}
 * )
 */
protected $children;
```

Comment: But, `orphanRemoval=true` will only work if the child has no other references to it. Once you add an additional reference, this will not work anymore.

Answer (score -2):

You could have:

```
$parent = $em->getRepository('Core\Parent')->find(1);
foreach($parent->getChildren() as $child) {
    $em->remove($child);
}
$parent->removeAllChildren();
$em->flush();
```